# Image registration params in OTB

Tags: orfeo-toolbox, coregistration

I have two images from two different time periods that are not registered (don't align) as shown below. I understand that image registration is possible using OTB's [FineRegistration](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_FineRegistration.html) feature. However I'm a bit confused as to what some of the required arguments mean. Specifically the **exploration radius (x and y) and metric radius (x and y)**. I have referred the function documentation but it's not immediately clear what these params do.

Could someone explain what these parameters are and their selection criteria?

[image: registration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fine tuning is done by iteratively by matching a block of pixel from image 1 with a block of pixels from image 2 at different position, until you find the best match.

The algorithm will test different relative position of the blocks (e.g. a one and a half pixel shift to the North) and converge to the optimal solution. Obviously, you don't want to check matching blocks that are 1000 km apart. First because it would take much much more time, second because you could be "trapped" in a local optimum that is not the global optimum.  The aim of the exploratory radius is to constraint the search of algo within a small distance to the original image. Try to figure out the shift between the images by looking at them, then take a slightly larger exploration radius.

There are different metric to identify when the matching is optimal (correlation, mutual information...), and these metric are based on all the pixels of a block. The size of the block is defined by the metric radius. Selecting the good size of the metric radius is more difficult: a small size will run faster and give relatively more importance to the central location, but you might not use all the context of the image (so, it is better for steep gradients in the image); a large uses more context but is will be slower and you could loose some very small details (so, it is better with smooth images). in any case, I recommend to use a metric radius larger than the exploration radius to avoid being trapped in a local optimum (in case a similar pattern repeats itself close to each other, like the tree between the roads on your image).